# MySQL CASE statement with INSTR

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that used to work, but now gives an error:

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.username, a.cb_voorletters, a.middlename, a.lastname, a.firstname,
CASE INSTR(b.email,'_skip_')
WHEN 0 THEN concat(b.email)
ELSE ''
END as email
FROM table1 AS a, table2 AS b
```

The error is: unexpected keyword (translated from dutch)

I assume that this is due to an earlier MySQL upgrade, but I can not find the cause.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Concat with only one argument?

Comment: The error message didn't point out where the `unexpected keyword` occur? Or at least tell what is the unexpected keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing to:

```
CASE 
WHEN INSTR(b.email,'_skip_') = 0 THEN concat(b.email)
ELSE ''
END as email,
```